# Platform Definition File

Tags: drivers, 18.04, kernel, nfc

I need to install a driver on Ubuntu with [this guide](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN11697.pdf) but i'm having some trouble with some parts of it.

***Below is the definition to be added to the platform definition file:***

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and dug around where the platform data file might be located and i saw `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/include/linux/platform_data/nxp-nci.h.` Is this the correct platform definition file?

***pn5xx_i2c.h must be included in the platform definition file***

since there was a part of the instruction that says "pn5xx_i2c.h file must be copied to include/linux kernel source sub-folder", to do this part i just referenced pn5xx_i2c.h in the nxp-nci.h file by adding:

```
#include<linux/pn5xx_i2c.h>
```

***Then the declared nfc_board_info structure must be added to the platform using dedicated procedure (platform specific).***

From my understanding, I'd have to edit this part of the code:

```
static struct i2c_board_info __initdata nfc_board_info[] = {
{
I2C_BOARD_INFO("pn547", 0x28),
.platform_data = &nfc_pdata,
},
};
```

that I added to the nxp-nci.h file and change 0x28 to whatever my platform is.

Assuming I did this part correctly, there should be a `/dev/pn544` device node created which i can check by running `cd /dev/` and `ls`. However, there is no pn544 device listed in my /dev folder so there must have been something wrong in one of the processes.

I also tried using device tree as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846993/platform-definition-file#comment84709893_48846993) but I did not find any .dts files from the `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/arch/arm/boot/dts` folder. I was also told that it might not be applicable because my PC is not an ARM-based Linux device.

Did I miss a process or could it be an NFC compatibility issue with Ubuntu?